# RESTful (or proper) MVC design for Landing Page with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest, restful-authentication

I've got a very simple question around Rails MVC/application design with a focus on being RESTful. I'm very, very new to Rails; this is in fact the first application I'm building on my own (though I've gone through [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org) and [Rails for Zombies 1 & 2](http://www.codeschool.com)).

**Goal:** I want to create a single page that collects email addresses - something very very similar to [early Mint prototypes](http://okdork.com/mint/?i=2), wherein before building their app they used a landing page to evaluate interest in the idea and test potential marketing messages.

**Approach:** My first instinct is to create a LandingPages controller and an Email model, and this actually worked very well until I got to the email collection form - at that point, I hit a bunch of snags writing Rspec tests and then application code.

Most of my troubles were around assigning the form, which was served by the LandingPages controller and view, but of course submitted data to the Email model.

**Question:** Is the two-model approach I suggested above appropriate? Or should I consolidate everything in to one Email(s) model & controller scheme? Might the separate be what caused my application code to get more complex, because I had Controller A interacting with Model B?

If the Approach above is appropriate, I will submit my actual code questions in another form. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of RESTfulness your form at the LandingPageController should point to EmailController#create. But no one will die if you don't do it that way.

What are the two models?

Comment: there is just one model - Email - it is the only data being stored or created in the app.

Comment: What do you mean with collection form? I dont understand whats your problem

Comment: the whole app is one page, on which I collect an email address using a single-field form tag and that's it. i had a LandingPages controller (to serve the page) and an Email model (to store the email collected) - that's it. that's my whole architecture/app. my main question is: when making such an app, is that bad? should the single page be served by an Emails controller that also interacts with the Email model?

Comment: No, there is no such best practice that says a controller should only use it's model. And you have a LandingPage, and it has no resource associated with it directly, so you really shouldn't follow Restful thinking on that.